# How to add array of items to a JavaFX table view

Tags: java, javafx

Following is my code. The items array has 12 elements. I want to add it to Table view. But it adds last item 12 times to the table. How can I fix this. Thanks.

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    col1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<View, String>("name"));
    col2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<View, String>("qty"));
    col3.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<View, String>("price"));

    ObservableList data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    View view = new View();
    table.setItems(data);

    for(Item item : items){
        view.name.set(item.getItem());
        view.price.set(String.valueOf(item.getPrice()));
        view.qty.set(String.valueOf(item.getAmount()));
        data.add(view);
    }

    lblTotalpr.setText(String.valueOf(ttl));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
View view = new View()
```

put this line inside for loop :)